# How did Crown fold the painting into his briefcase?

Tags: the-thomas-crown-affair

In The Thomas Crown Affair (1999) a painting is stolen and folded into a briefcase.  Crown doesn't even have time to remove the stretchers.  The painting is later seen no worse for wear.  What magic did he have in that briefcase?

Comment: Hard to imagine an art lover would fold the canvas and risk damage. Odd that such a thematic and physical error would blow by in a film with pretensions to clever characters, actions, plans and motives...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to IMDB this is a Continuity error.

> When Thomas steals the Monet in the first theft, he puts the painting with wooden canvas stretcher into his briefcase and folds it closed. When he opens the briefcase later, the canvas stretcher is not broken.

Comment: In other words the issue is comprehensively ignored by the film. Talk fast, act like it doesn't matter and hope the audience doesn't think too much...

Answer (score 16):

A [quote](http://feelinglistless.blogspot.com/2004/04/scene-unseen-thomas-crown-affair-take.html) from John McTiernan, the director:

> "Anyway we did an elaborate thing of folding the painting into the
>   brief case and people were so offended by it that I sorta hadda cut it
>   out and make it much briefer."